# Leaflet: Access Coordinates from map.locate({setView: true, maxZoom: 16});

Tags: leaflet

Does anyone know how to access the latLng data from Leaflet's .locate method?

I'd rather use that than calling html5 navigate...

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual `locate` method of `L.Map` doesn't return the coordinates. If you need the coordinates you can get those by listening to the `locationfound` event on your `L.Map` instance. When fired it returns a `LocationEvent` containing the coordinates and much more:

```
var map = new L.Map(...)

map.locate()

map.on('locationfound', function (locationEvent) {
  console.log(locationEvent)
})
```

- http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-locationfound
- http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#location-event

Comment: Thanks.  Also, I just found map.getCenter() !  Doh!